# SQL : File Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, t-sql

Is there a way that I can check a file if it is existing with the first 8 letter/numbers only? Because the filename is `201402195678`. The Filename is changing everyday for example for today it is `201402195678.txt` and for tomorrow `201402201956.txt`. The first 8 digits are the current date. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you use SQL to see if a file exists? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Because I'm doing a sql job that will send reports to the email if the file exist or not. Thanks

Comment: It is better to use SSIS packages for such kind of tasks. But you can also check if the file exists using `dbo.xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: You are asking to just validate if the name is well formed to actually check if the file exist you must check in the file system (or filetable or whatever you are using as a "storage"). BTW if the name is string representation of a datetime, just try to cast it back to datetime to check if its valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sys.sysfiles catalog view to see files description.
in order to filter files which names are first 8 digits use below trick to track them.

```
SELECT *
    FROM SYS.sysfiles
    WHERE NAME LIKE'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```